# CGRect not appearing with gradient sublayer

Tags: swift

CGRect not appearing at the same time as gradient sublayer, it's one or the other

Drawing only the gradient layer or only the rectangle works fine.

```
    guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { fatalError() }
    ctx.setFillColor(red: 1, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
    let segment1 = CGRect(x: 20, y: 110, width: 30, height: 10)
    ctx.fill(segment1)

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 0.29, green: 0.56, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 0.23, green: 0.19, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1).cgColor]
    layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

I was expecting them both to appear in the correct order

Comment: where are you executing this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `gradient.render(in: ctx)` instead of `layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0` and draw `segement1` after that: (Assuming you are doing this in a custom view class)

```
class customView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { fatalError() }

        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 0.29, green: 0.56, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 0.23, green: 0.19, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        gradient.render(in: ctx)

        ctx.setFillColor(red: 1, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
        let segment1 = CGRect(x: 20, y: 110, width: 30, height: 10)
        ctx.fill(segment1)
    }
}
```

This way you aren't using the `CGGraphicsContext` in addition to the `CALayer`, you are just using the `CGGraphicsContext` because you layer gets rendered using the `ctx`

Comment: This works but there's one problem - when I render the custom UIView as an image for sharing, the background is black and rectangles are gone.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean, you might want to post a question